# Loading text from a txt file depending on day of week

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am using this which loads images depending on day of the week, but I also would like to show text and load it from a file, too. I like to use it as todays menu, so the cook uploads text files, like monday.txt tuesday.txt, and does not need to mess up with coding.

```
<html>

<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">

<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="60">
<title>LOUNAS</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var imlocation = "";
 function ImageArray (n) {
   this.length = n;
   for (var i =1; i <= n; i++) {
     this[i] = ' '
   }
 }
image = new ImageArray(7);
image[0] = 'sunday.jpg';
image[1] = 'monday.jpg';
image[2] = 'tuesday.jpg';
image[3] = 'wednsday.jpg';
image[4] = 'thursday.jpg';
image[5] = 'friday.jpg';
image[6] = 'saturday.jpg';
var currentdate = new Date();
var imagenumber = currentdate.getDay();
document.write('<img src="' + imlocation + image[imagenumber] + '"> style="width:100%;height:100%;" border="0" /');
//--></script></head>

<body bgcolor="#000000">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX request in order to read files from the server.
(If your intention is to display the data to client and not self-display site)

You'll need a server and back-end language like PHP, and then you'll need to make an AJAX request to server depend on the day of the week (meaning which url?) and then display the data.

Second, about what you did, using `document.write` it's not best way, becuase it clear the page after using and all the data that you had will gone (meaning HTML), and also create element this way dosen't work good in all browsers , you should use `createElement` instead.

Also, you can use CSS to give style to that element instead of doing it via JavaScript